# Get IP address of connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I's like to process the IP address and user agent of each signalr connection to my hub. To do this, I have overridden the OnConnected method as shown below.

```
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            string UserAgent = Context.Headers["User-Agent"];

            var Request = Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Request;
            string IPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;

            // code to process IP address and user agent goes here

            return base.OnConnected();
        }
```

Is there a more robust way to retrieve the IP address? The call to Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Request sometimes fails. Using fiddler, I can see that most failures occur if web sockets are used for the underlying connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest pulling the IP address from OWIN's environment dictionary directly:

- http://owin.org/
- http://owin.org/spec/owin-1.0.0.html
- http://owin.org/spec/CommonKeys.html

`Request.GetHttpContext()` actually works by getting the `HttpContextBase` from the environment dictionary:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the <see cref="HttpContextBase"/> for this <see cref="IRequest"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request">The request</param>
public static HttpContextBase GetHttpContext(this IRequest request)
{
    object httpContextBaseValue;
    if (request.Environment.TryGetValue(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName, out httpContextBaseValue))
    {
        return httpContextBaseValue as HttpContextBase;
    }

    return null;
}
```

You could write something similar specifically for getting the IP address:

```
public static string GetRemoteIpAddress(this IRequest request)
{
    object ipAddress;
    if (request.Environment.TryGetValue("server.RemoteIpAddress", out ipAddress))
    {
        return ipAddress as string;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Not only is this likely more robust, but it also has a much better chance of still working if you port your application to another web server (or perhaps self-host).